# Removing all images with class depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, html

I have to erase all the images from div if the screen.width is lower, than 870px.
The code looks more/less like this:

```
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="first">
    <img scr="1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img scr="2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
let screenWidth = screen.width;
imgRemove = document.querySelector(".main-page img");
if (screenWidth<870) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    imgRemove.parentNode.removeChild(imgRemove);
  }
}
```

Problem is this only deletes the first of the images. Any idea how to erase all of them from `.main-page`?

Comment: You can add querySelectorAll and counter [i] in the for loop. imgRemove[i]

Comment: instead of using for loop just use foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `querySelector` To [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
2. And add increment with indexof `imgRemove` element with in loop
3. Then change the remove function to `imgRemove[i].remove();` .Because  already target is a img

**JS**

```
let screenWidth = screen.width;
imgRemove = document.querySelectorAll(".main-page img");
if (screenWidth < 870) {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgRemove.length; i++) {
    imgRemove[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier in my opinion - just to use a CSS media query to hide all images with a certain class. Rather than removing them from the DOM directly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
    .main-page img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using for loop just use foreach loop